# Matrix Multiplication in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I tried to implement matrix multiplication in pyspark, but it seems that there is something wrong with the multiply() function, could anyone help me with that?
Thank you!

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    import sys
    #define multiplication method
    def multiply(x):
        res = []
        for a in x[1]:
            if a[0] != 'A':
                continue
            else:
                for b in x[1]:
                    if b[0] != 'B':
                        continue
                    else:
                        res.union(((a[1], b[1]), (a[2]*b[2])))
        return res

    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MatrixMultiplication")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    matA = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
    matB = sc.textfile(sys.argv[2])


    matA = matA.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
    matA = matA.map(lambda x:(x[1], ('A', x[0], x[2])))

    matB = matB.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
    matB = matB.map(lambda x:(x[0], ('B', x[1], x[2])))

    mat = matA.union(matB)
    mat = mat.groupByKey()

    matC = mat.flatMap(multiply).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
    output = matC.collect()
    f = open(sys.argv[3], 'w')
    for x in output:
        f.write(str(x[0][0]) + ',' + str(x[0][1])+'\t' + str(x[1]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Can you include the error or unexpected results you are getting?

Comment: something like 'unicode cannot be multiply'

Comment: try converting unicode `char`s to `int`s

Comment: can you also include the format of input?